# facebook signed_request doesn't contain 'liked' parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to check whether a user has liked my app using this code:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$liked = $signed_request['page']['liked'];
echo($liked);
```

But it doesn't return anything. On the other hand, if I do:

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$expires = $signed_request['expires'];
echo($expires);
```

it does return an appropriate value.
Is this something to do with permissions?

thanks

Comment: Are you try it in a canvas apps or page tab?

Comment: The app is set to be displayed in Canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get page info parameters with signed_request only if it is a page tab application. If it is a canvas app, you can get like info with a FQL query:

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id="PAGE_ID" and uid = me()
```

Comment: So how do i do it for a Canvas app?

Comment: canvas apps are not linked to any page, so there is no liked status, of course

Comment: Thanks,  isn't FQL deprecated?

Comment: Do I need a special permission from a user to run this query?

Comment: No, basic permisson is enough.

Comment: $params = array(
 'method' => 'fql.query',
 'query' => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='XXXXXXXXXX' and uid = me()",
);
  
$result = $facebook->api($params);

Comment: How should I parse the $result?

Comment: $isLiked = ($result != false && isset($result[0])); Check this https://github.com/aykutfarsak/simplefacebook/blob/master/src/simple_facebook.php#L459

Comment: Hmm,  it seems that $result[0] is never set. Even though I have liked the page. any ideas?  thanks

Comment: I assume that PAGE_ID is same as App ID ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19880/discussion-between-astralmaster-and-aykut)

Comment: I don't think I can figure what's the PAGE_ID and how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

#### For new applications this field is no longer available.

> This field will no longer be included for any app created after the
>   launch of v2.1 (August 7th, 2014), and will be permanently set to true
>   for all other apps on November 5th, 2014.

See the reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request